# JUnit JPA database schema validation

Tags: validation, jpa, junit, schema

In my project I am using JPA 2.0 persistence (hibernate). I would like to write a simple JUnit test case which checks:

(1) Whether the tables corresponding to the persisted classes already exist in the target database

(2) If (1) returns "true" for a particular persisted class (i.e. a table with the specifed name exists) than it checks whether the database table definition is compatible with the JPA entity (i.e. the type of the columns and the constraints are same or compatible)

Can you provide me with a simple receipe for such a JUnit test?

Comment: just change hbm2ddl.auto to validate, no need for unit tests

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Can you give me an example of how to return TRUE/FALSE? I do have a case where the table might be changed outside of the scope of Java so need to raise an exception if such discrepancy is detected.